# Rename column names using dictionary and regular expression

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, rename

I have a DataFrame called mcmc_samples which contains Markov-Chain-Monte-Carlo Samples for multiple variables

| deviance | K_1[1,1] | K_1[1,2] | K_1[1,3] | K_1[2,1] | K_1[2,2] | K_1[2,3] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.6 | 0.1 | 0.3 | 0.9 | 0.8 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

The columns names are composed of the level (K_1), the variable (first number in brackets before comma) and the category (second number in brackets after comma).

I try to rename the column names such that the numbers in the brackets are more meaningful. For this purpose, I want to use the following dictionaries.

```
dict_var = {1: "variable_1", 2: "variable_2"}
dict_categ  = {1: "item_1, 2: "item_2", 3: "item_3"}
```

I tried to replace the strings using regular expression

```
mcmc_samples.columns = mcmc_samples.columns.str.replace(r"(?<=,)(.*?)(?=\])", 
mcmc_samples.columns.str.extract(r"(?<=,)(.*?)(?=\])")[0].map(dict_categ), regex=True)
```

but this gave me the following error:

TypeError: repl must be a string or callable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the dictionaries contain comprehensive data and all numbers you will match will have corresponding keys in the dictionaries, you can use

```py
mcmc_samples.columns = mcmc_samples.columns.str.replace(
    r"(?<=\[)(\d+),(\d+)(?=])",
    lambda x: f"{dict_var[int(x.group(1))]},{dict_categ[int(x.group(2))]}",
    regex=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DTCq0a/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=\[)` - right before, there must be a `[` char
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `,` - a comma
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `(?=])` - right after, there must be a `]` char.

If you need to return the matched number if it is not present in the dictionaries you can use

```py
def repl(x):
    result = []
    if int(x.group(1)) in dict_var:
        result.append(dict_var[int(x.group(1))])
    else:
        result.append(x.group(1))
    if int(x.group(2)) in dict_categ:
        result.append(dict_categ[int(x.group(2))])
    else:
        result.append(x.group(2))
    return ",".join(result)

mcmc_samples.columns = mcmc_samples.columns.str.replace(
    r"(?<=\[)(\d+),(\d+)(?=])",
    lambda x: repl(x),
    regex=True)
```